# Programmatically Setting Number Input Value Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of javascript that sets the number input value. However, it won't work. The input's value field is still empty after the call (although console.log() outputing the element's val() does show the correct value). I have tried setting the value three ways jQuery's .val(total), .attr('value', total), and with plain old .value =, and still nothing. I even replaced the entire element with html and the value concatenated into the value attribute, and it won't work.

Any ideas why this won't take?

Here's the markup:

```
<div id="proposal_price_box">
  <div class="proposal_price_header sys_bkgcolor">
    <span class="title"><h3>Price to Appear on Proposal</h3></span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <span class="label">$</span>
    <input type="number" class="amount-input" id="proposal_price" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the pertinent javascript:

```
$('#proposal_price').val('1234');
```

Jsfiddle demonstrating the problem below.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8z9K/12/

Somehow, if the element's container is displayed, it will set the value. But as soon as its hidden again, it breaks.

**EDIT** Sorry, I didn't properly demonstrate the problem in JSfiddle. I am trying to clone the contents of the container and place it elsewhere. I've updated the jsfiddle to better show the issue.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Working for me, using Chrome.

Comment: Working for me, too. I'm using Safari on OS X. Do you use e.g. Firefox with NoScript? Or do you block ActiveX in IE?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't properly demonstrate the problem in JSfiddle. I am trying to clone the contents of the container and place it elsewhere. I've updated the jsfiddle to better show the issue.

Comment: realized I have to update the revision number on the jsfiddle url. Should be correct now.

Comment: I don't know what it is yet, but your cloning renders your markup invalid because the cloned element has the same ID as the initial element. (And ID should be unique!)

Comment: Good eye. I didn't post it, but I go through the cloned element and remove the ids (setting them as classes instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between an input node's value and its value attribute.
When you assign its value with the val() method, you're setting its value, not its value attribute.
When you use the html() method you are getting the html with all attributes (including the value attribute), but that attribute has not changed thru your val() assignment.
Only the node's value has changed.

Comment: I've resolved it, thanks Marty. I had tried using the attr before but it didn't work (and I'm not sure why, there was other code interfering somehow). I cleaned my code up and it worked this time. Wish I hadn't shot down the first answer, that person was correct as well. Either way, your answer caused me to stop and think about the problem more clearly. Cheers!

Comment: I think I found the answer @MattAikens

Answer (score 0):

You do `#proposal_price { display: none; }`. If you that element, it keeps the same ID (that is actually invalid, but modern browser can handle this). Thus, it remains hidden because of the `display: none;` you should remove the ID of the clone, otherwise the clone won't be displayed either.

Yep, this jQuery seems to solve it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#proposal_price').val('123');
    console.log("before clone");
    clone = $('#proposal_container').clone();
    clone.attr("id", "");
    console.log("after clone");
    $('body').append(clone.html());
});
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense! Chrome and Safari are both WebKit browsers! Do you have it uploaded so I can view it with iPhone safari? @MattAikens

Comment: The jsfiddle entry is updated and works in all three. In my app however, it only works in the first two. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Perhaps you somewhere override the CSS styling? What is the styling for `.amount-input`?

Comment: For whatever reason in iPAd on my app I can't retrieve or set the value from/on the hidden input. I ended up having to set the value in the clone after replacing the id with the class. My next problem is trying to set an element's html() using that hidden one with the id. Can't do it..will just use the variable and do it in that function.

Comment: For a new issue post a new question @MattAikens

Comment: yep no worries, I've resolved it. I'm just perplexed that iPad Safari can't retrieve the value from a hidden input, even when using .attr(). Luckily I had another recourse.